# I am reading an image with cv2.imread(), and converting it to grayscale. However why is it not in grayscale when I display it?

Tags: python, ocr

I went to read up the syntax of cv2.imread() method and it says that specifying the flag=0 will load the image in grayscale.

The original image is this:

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQWiI.png)

And I executed the following code with the following libs, no errors.

> `import cv2`
> `import pytesseract`
> `import matplotlib`
> `import image`

`img=cv2.imread("C:/Users/HP_Demo/Desktop/cv2/sample02.png",0)`

`plt.imshow(img)`

`plt.show()`

The result is this:
[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2bFb.png)

Comment: `img = cv2.imread(path)`
`img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`
Could you please try these lines of code and see if it solves your problem?

Comment: `gray_img = cv2.imread(path, 0)`
`cv2.imshow(gray_img)` 
This also.

Comment: `img = cv2.imread(path)` `img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`
is working to produce the image in gray but it resulted in other errors downsteam.

@ombk

Comment: `gray_img = cv2.imread(path, 0)` `cv2.imshow(gray_img)` returned an error hence i edited to `cv2.imshow(' ', gray_img)` and added an waitkey(0) and it returned just like the original image.

@ombk

Comment: hey man, I tried the code, both of them on a different image, they produce a good grayscale mode. I believe since your original image is in black and white, you won't really see the difference.

Comment: any luck with the method?

Comment: The method is alright, I guess the original image fed into could be the error. @ombk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import cv2 

img=cv2.imread("colorful.png",1)
cv2.imshow("",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Result:**

[image: colorful]

```
import cv2 

img=cv2.imread("colorful.png",0) # same image changed the 1 to 0
cv2.imshow("",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Result:**

[image: GrayGray]

**Conclusion**

As I said in a comment maybe the image you used is causing the no grayscale.

Comment: Thanks man, it could be the image that is causing no grayscale.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really know but try using that: `cv2.imread("path", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).`

PS. And it is better to use `sys.path.join()` instead of raw /